# String.matches not matching pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
String resultOfSplit="0x^3";
boolean startzero = resultOfSplit.matches("^0");
System.out.println(startzero);
```

I want to find if the first character of my string is equal to "0" or no
but `startzero` is false!

Comment: why dont you check `resultOfSplit.startsWith("0");`

Comment: yes. it will be good.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `String.matches`, which will match against the whole `String`.

Try this instead:

```
//                                         | start of input
//                                         || "0" 
//                                         ||| any character, 0 or more instances
boolean startzero = resultOfSplit.matches("^0.*");
```

As mentioned by [Rustam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2447152/rustam), there is an easier and more elegant solution without using regex:

```
boolean startzero = resultOfSplit.startsWith("0");
```

Comment: @user4149885 no probs :)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 boolean startzero = resultOfSplit.startsWith("0");
```